# How can make a FileProvider available to other applications?

Tags: android, provider, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider

Is it possible to have a FileProvider available to other applications ?

manifest.xml

```
...
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="false"
        android:permission="com.example.filesvisible.permission.READ" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filespath" />
    </provider>
...
```

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html):

> false: The provider is not available to other applications. Set
>   android:exported="false" to limit access to the provider to your
>   applications. Only applications that have the same user ID (UID) as
>   the provider will have access to it.

I've tried to set exported to true but I got this exception 
`Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported` Why I can't export a FileProvider ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a FileProvider available to other applications ?

Yes. That is usually the point.

> Why I can't export a FileProvider ?

Because that is not how you use a `FileProvider`.

The point behind `FileProvider` is to [give *select* access to files to third-party apps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions). You can do this by `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`, in the `Intent` that you use to pass one of your provider's `Uri` values to the third-party app (e.g., via an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` used with `startActivity()`).

Also see [the training guide on sharing files](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html).

Comment: Hi. i used your advises and everything is fine but when i want to share soundfile using bluetooth an error occur and say bluetooth is stopped. i think it is because bluetooth has not permission to read file from my app folder. how can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: this is my code:this is my code: sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(_context,"ir.khazan.ringtone.fileprovider",newSoundFile_in_app_folder));
                        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
                        Utils.activity.startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: @karimkhan: "how can i solve this?" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the other app. Ask a separate question on Stack Overflow, with your code and that stack trace, if you do not understand it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it possible to implement the custom call method for File Providers and access that method in another application? I would like my other application to be able to list all files in a directory but cannot because I get an error about trying to access a provider that is not exported.

Comment: @GingerMcMurray: If you mean [this `call()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider?hl=en#call(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)), *implementing* it probably is fine. *Calling* it could get interesting because of the exported issue. Off the top of my head, I can't think of how to set it up that you can call it. You might consider using another IPC option in lieu of `call()`, such as a bound service.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by adding a ContentProvider for the call method. The ContentProvider does nothing except implement call. There is still a FileProvider for manipulating and accessing the files. It's not elegant but it gets the job done.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have another issue. I can't actually open a file using the content provider. I get the same error that it isn't exported. Note: I'm trying to do this programatically by calling InputStream is = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri). The exception I get is "Permission Denial: opening provider com.global.fb.tms.DownloadedFileProvider from ProcessRecord that is not exported from UID." How are we supposed to use FileProviders if they can't be exported?

Comment: @GingerMcMurray: `FileProvider` is designed for the app with the provider to send a `Uri` with permissions to another app, such as in the "data" facet of an `Intent` for `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: @CommonsWare can I not construct a URI manually since I know what files are there and what the authority is? My app has been granted URI permissions to the file. If not then how can I share files with other applications without using intents? I control both the provider and the user so can jump through any hoops needed to make this work. I have one app which downloads files for other apps in our ecosystem to consume.

Comment: @GingerMcMurray: "how can I share files with other applications without using intents?" -- implement your own `ContentProvider` that does not share the limitations of `FileProvider`. `FileProvider` is for a specific pattern and is not designed to address all scenarios of sharing streams between apps. Note that securing a custom `ContentProvider`, such that the content is only available to one other app, can be tricky. That's part of the reason why `FileProvider` has its limitations: to simplify the security aspects.

Comment: @Commonsware are there any examples of handling files with ContentProviders? Those seem geared to databases.

Comment: @GingerMcMurray: I cover the subject in [this older free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/). See the "Content Provider Theory" and "Content Provider Implementation Patterns" chapters.

Comment: @CommonsWare awesome, thanks! That did the trick perfectly. :)